# Pandas rolling removes imaginary part of complex... defect or feature?

Tags: python, pandas, complex-numbers, rolling-computation

Pandas rolling appears only to return the real part of complex values...

Am I missing something?

```
a=np.array([[1+0j,2+0j,3+0j],[4j,5j,10+6j]])
pd.DataFrame(a.T).rolling(3).apply(lambda x: print(x) is None)
```

Output:

```
0   1
1   2
2   3
dtype: float64
0    0
1    0
2   10
dtype: float64
    0   1
0   NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN
2   1   1
```

Note that the problem is not with apply.
When apply is used without rolling, the entire complex value is passed to the lambda function:

```
a=np.array([[1+0j,2+0j,3+0j],[4j,5j,10+6j]])
pd.DataFrame(a.T).apply(lambda x: print(x) is None)
```

Output:

```
0   1+0j
1   2+0j
2   3+0j
Name: 0, dtype: complex128
0    0+4j
1    0+5j
2   10+6j
Name: 1, dtype: complex128
0    True
1    True
dtype: bool
```

** Note: this is not a question of whether or not to use rolling - but rather about the behavior of rolling with complex values.

---

- Update: the issue persists on Pandas 1.5.1

Comment: I can reproduce the issue. I used `np.sum` as aggregation function. You should probably open a bug report if not existing.

Comment: @alps: You mentioned you've opened a related GitHub issue. Do you happen to have the link?

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/46619 - was relabeled from "Bug" to "Enhancement". Seems there's a fix in the works: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/47028

Answer (score 1):

I just changed the mentioned line in the warning `ensure_float64` because it checks the values to be float64, as follows:

```
values = values
```

Then changed the dtype as it produces buffer error, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a=np.array([[1+0j,2+0j,3+0j],[4j,5j,10+6j]])
pd.DataFrame(a.T).astype(np.complex64).rolling(3).apply(lambda x: print(x) is None)
```

The result:

```
0    1.0+0.0j
1    2.0+0.0j
2    3.0+0.0j
dtype: complex64
0     0.0+4.0j
1     0.0+5.0j
2    10.0+6.0j
dtype: complex64
0   1
0   NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN
2   1.0 1.0
```

rolling file location:

C:\Users\user\anaconda3\pkgs\pandas-1.2.4-py38hd77b12b_0\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window

line to edit: 348.

Comment: This still returns float64 for me. Also the warning does not display.

Comment: Correction: the warning does display - but what @keramat suggests still returns float64.

Comment: Did you change the line specified in the pandas package code?

Comment: Ah indeed. Would you mind posting a monkey patch version of the replacement?

Comment: Look at answer again, and see if it helps now.